# Setting button signals for widget created via wrapper function

Tags: python, pyqt

I am trying to create a GUI (see attached screenshot) where it has about 6 sets of widgets where each set comprises of QLabel, QLineEdit and QPushButton.

Instead of writing the widgets and the layout again and again, I thought of writing up a wrapper function such that I will only need to write up 6 lines for the creation.

However, while this works efficiently for me in terms of the widgets creation, I realized that  I am not able to set the Signal for the button(s) as I do not know the widget's names.

What will be the best way to set the signals if I decided to use this wrapper methodology?

The following is a screenshot of what I am trying to achieve as well as my code:

```
class MyDevTool(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyDevTool, self).__init__(parent)
        self._create_ui()

    def _create_hbox_layout(self, label):
        h_layout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        label = QtGui.QLabel(label)
        label.setFixedWidth(80)
        line_edit = QtGui.QLineEdit()
        push_btn = QtGui.QPushButton("<<<")

        h_layout.addWidget(label)
        h_layout.addWidget(line_edit)
        h_layout.addWidget(push_btn)

        return h_layout


    def _create_ui(self):
        main_layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        main_layout.addLayout(
            self._create_hbox_layout("Input Directory")
        )
        main_layout.addLayout(
            self._create_hbox_layout("Output Directory")
        )

        self.setLayout(main_layout)
```

[image: ui]

Comment: What information do you want the new signal to return to you if you press the n-th row?

Comment: I am trying to do something like `<button name>.clicked.connect(<some function>)`. For example, in the screenshot I have given, both buttons will open up a file browser but targeted at specific file extensions. Eg. InputDirectory button will look for .json format while OutputDirectory button will set the path with .txt. It is the <button name> part that I am having trouble with

Comment: A class must be generic, not depend on outside, it must be transparent, so I ask what information do you want to return when you press one of the buttons?

Comment: You are going down a bad path, if you want to create a generic widget you must think what information you want the signal to transport, for example QListView returns a QModelIndex when it is clicked, that QModelIndex has the information of the item pressed, the same with other widgets ,

Comment: For example, it could be that the input to the widget as a process is the extensions for each row, and when a button is pressed the QFileDialog is created internally, the files are selected and then a personalized signal indicates which extension (or row) the data comes from , in addition to the data.

Comment: I see, I guess that may be a bit hard for my GUI then but to write out each lines, as I have some calling out a file dialog, and some calling from some other functions from other scripts..

Comment: Well, then you do not want to generalize, what exactly do you want to do?

Comment: you could pass the name of the callback to the function _create_hbox_layout

Comment: @dissidia. Use a container class, not a method - then you can expose the component widgets as attributes.